# Clicking QSystemTrayIcon brings up an empty context menu on Mate desktop

Tags: c++, qt, system-tray, trayicon

I'd like to create a tray icon for my application for showing the main window on clicking on it after the former was minimized.

Here's the implementation:

TrayIcon.h:

```
class TrayIcon_t : public QSystemTrayIcon {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TrayIcon_t();
};
```

TrayIcon.cpp:

```
TrayIcon_t::TrayIcon_t() {
    setIcon(QIcon(":/icons/tray.ico"));
}
```

Main.cpp (part only, there's no more code related to the tray):

```
TrayIcon_t *tray = new TrayIcon_t;
QObject::connect(tray, SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)), &MainWindow, SLOT(show()));
tray->show();
```

While on LXDE it works just fine, on MATE desktop it mostly opens a small menu (I think) containing no items and doesn't emit the signal required by the main window to be shown. [See this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxUlt.png)

Do you think I've encountered a bug in Qt 5.7.0?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is a bug. Reported it and became accepted at:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-55717